# Link Two Comboboxes vb net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Combobox2 values need to be changed when combobox1 changes value

```
    Private Sub ComboBoxPodelba_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxPodelba.SelectedIndexChanged

            Dim myconnect As New SqlConnection
            myconnect.ConnectionString = Common.connectionString

            Dim mycommand2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
            mycommand2.Connection = myconnect

            Try
                myconnect.Open()
                mycommand2.CommandText = "select PodPodelbaIme from PodPodelba where PodelbaFK = '" + ComboBoxPodelba.SelectedValue.ToString + "'"

                Dim reader2 As SqlDataReader
                reader2 = mycommand2.ExecuteReader()
                Dim dt2 As DataTable = New DataTable
                dt2.Load(reader2)
                ComboBoxPOdPodelba.ValueMember = "PodPodelbaIme"
                ComboBoxPOdPodelba.DisplayMember = "PodPodelbaIme"
                ComboBoxPOdPodelba.DataSource = dt2

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End Sub
```

Comment: So you need to trigger the population of the second combobox when the first is changed. Use the Change event.

Comment: Change event on first or second .. Can you show me @Mych

Comment: Change event on first. So when the first one is change it will trigger the event which will populate the second with the correct values based on the value of the first. Do a search for cascading dropdowns or cascading combobox.

Comment: ComboBox2.ValueMember = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString                                                                                                                     I try this and have an error now : Cannot bind to the new value member. @Mych

Comment: Your code is triggered on ComboBoxPodelba_SelectedIndexChanged (this should be your first combo. The code within the event is targeting ComboBoxPOdPodelba this should be the second combo. You can use Sender instead of Combo1 in the sql command text... see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Private Sub Combo1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combo1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim myconnect As New SqlConnection
        myconnect.ConnectionString = Common.connectionString

        Dim mycommand2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        mycommand2.Connection = myconnect

        Try
            myconnect.Open()
            mycommand2.CommandText = "select PodPodelbaIme from PodPodelba where PodelbaFK = '" + Sender.SelectedValue.ToString + "'"

            Dim reader2 As SqlDataReader
            reader2 = mycommand2.ExecuteReader()
            Dim dt2 As DataTable = New DataTable
            dt2.Load(reader2)
            Combo2.ValueMember = "PodPodelbaIme"
            Combo2.DisplayMember = "PodPodelbaIme"
            Combo2.DataSource = dt2

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: If this solution was right please mark... if not please publish correct code so that i may help others. Thanks